# Print MAC address from Ethernet header

Tags: c, linux-kernel, iptables

I want to check the Ethernet header of packet that is porececed by iptables (1.4), so i need to write a module that catch packet and apply my function. I am looking for the mac destination value in the Ethernet header (just for test purpose), so the code should be like this:

```
static bool match(const struct sk_buff *skb, struct xt_action_param *par)
{
    struct ethhdr *hdr;        
    hdr = eth_hdr(skb);
    printk(KERN_INFO "hdr->h_dest 0x%x\n", hdr->h_dest);
    printk(KERN_INFO "MACPROTO=%04x\n", hdr->h_proto);
```

The problem is that i cant get the correct value, i have some thing that is not even in the real frame (i checked that with Wireshark), so is it the right function to get Ethernet header attributs?

**update:**
i used the solution presented in the post, but still have wrong output, it's like if the structure point to wrong place
[image]

This image show result when i use nc to send "aaa" string, the ethernet header should be the same in the to frame, but as present in the result, it's not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`struct ethhdr` is defined as such:

```
/*
 *  This is an Ethernet frame header.
 */

struct ethhdr {
    unsigned char   h_dest[ETH_ALEN];   /* destination eth addr */
    unsigned char   h_source[ETH_ALEN]; /* source ether addr    */
    __be16      h_proto;        /* packet type ID field */
} __attribute__((packed));
```

**But your code is trying to print that byte array using `%x`:**

```
printk(KERN_INFO "hdr->h_dest 0x%x\n", hdr->h_dest);
```

That makes no sense, and probably causes a compiler warning to be generated. This is kernel code - you *are* using `-Werror` and `-Wall`, *right?*

---

Good news: `printk` supports printing MAC addresses directly. From [`documentation/printk-formats.txt`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/printk-formats.txt?v=4.5#L136):

```
MAC/FDDI addresses:

    %pM 00:01:02:03:04:05
    %pMR    05:04:03:02:01:00
    %pMF    00-01-02-03-04-05
    %pm 000102030405
    %pmR    050403020100

    For printing 6-byte MAC/FDDI addresses in hex notation. The 'M' and 'm' 
    specifiers result in a printed address with ('M') or without ('m') byte
    separators. The default byte separator is the colon (':').

    Where FDDI addresses are concerned the 'F' specifier can be used after
    the 'M' specifier to use dash ('-') separators instead of the default
    separator.

    For Bluetooth addresses the 'R' specifier shall be used after the 'M' 
    specifier to use reversed byte order suitable for visual interpretation
    of Bluetooth addresses which are in the little endian order.

    Passed by reference.
```

So you can just use this:

```
printk(KERN_INFO "hdr->h_dest 0x%pM\n", hdr->h_dest);
```

These format specifiers are provided anywhere `vsnprintf` is used. Here's [an example](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv4/netfilter/nf_log_ipv4.c?v=4.5#L290):

```
    switch (dev->type) {
    case ARPHRD_ETHER:
            nf_log_buf_add(m, "MACSRC=%pM MACDST=%pM MACPROTO=%04x ",
                           eth_hdr(skb)->h_source, eth_hdr(skb)->h_dest,
                           ntohs(eth_hdr(skb)->h_proto));
            return;
    default:
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Good to know. I had never heard %pM and friends. +1

Comment: I used %x to print the ouptut in hexa, so that i can verify the result easly with wireshark, anyway, i try your method, i used %pM, but still have the wrong output , proto that is equal to 0000 (wireshark show 0800)

Comment: @yassine The `%x` specifier prints an `unsigned int` while `h_dest` is an array of `unsigned char`. If you don't understand why this is wrong then you shouldn't be writing kernel drivers yet. Also, your code never mentions anything about printing the protocol field.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart,  i used the same line to print proto type; printk(KERN_INFO "MACPROTO=%04x\n", hdr->h_proto);

Comment: Finaly i used another packet generator, and the packet seem to be printed withouht error, thanks

Comment: @yassine, you may use **%\*ph** for hexdump. Basically **%pM** and **%6phC** are equivalent.